# Cannot import Google Trends API, pytrends

Tags: python, api, google-trends

Hello Could you guys help me to see why after install pytrends,
I still cannot use it.
Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKJjT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0tZi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htPWm.png)

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'

Comment: From the images, it shows that `pytrends` has already been installed into that conda environment. Are you sure you are activating and using the correct environment in your jupyter notebook? Maybe if you could share a full image of your jupyter notebook to see what environment is being used? In your terminal with your conda environment activated, if you type `python` and then `import pytrends` in the python session, do you still get an error?

Comment: Hi man, so yeah i have no problem importing it from anaconda prompt cmd,, but when i use the jupyter notebook from the activated environment (see second image)with pip installed to import that package i show this error code

Comment: so maybe is my IDE problem?

Comment: Your jupyter notebook may not be using the right kernel. Have a look at what kernel your notebook is using and if that corresponds to the environment that you have installed your dependencies in, and maybe take a look at this https://towardsdatascience.com/get-your-conda-environment-to-show-in-jupyter-notebooks-the-easy-way-17010b76e874